# regular expression for country code

Tags: php, regex

Regular expression for country code like +91 for India

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? What do you want to do?

Comment: If i could vote this down i would.

Comment: @Chris: I did it for you. And for me. And for humanity.

Answer (score 8):

Is it a question ? If you want to get a regexp to match country code like `+` with two digits, then use:

```
/(\+\d{2})/
```

Comment: can you pls tell a regex for between 1 digit to 3 digits after the +

Comment: @Lakshay `/(\+\d{1,3})/`